# R: issues when loading package 'normalize_names_replacement_value' not found

Tags: r, package

I am using the following command from library `decompTumor2Sig`:

```
library(decompTumor2Sig)

# fname is the filename with mpf data
genomes <- readGenomesFromMPF(fname, numBases=3)

# first few lines of fname (tab-delimited)
Patient chr1    35192318    G   A
Patient chr1    55156906    A   -
Patient chr1    118008099   C   T
Patient chr1    147758514   C   T
Patient chr1    230978735   CAG -
Patient chr2    188988535   T   C
Patient chr2    189004144   GTAAGTAACTTCATTTTTTTAAATTGATTCTACTATTTTGATTTTTATCACAAATCGATTAGAGAAAAACACTGTCACATAAAGATGAGCTAAGTCTTCATTATCTGTATTAG   -
Patient chr3    57035053    A   G
Patient chr3    108464735   A   T
Patient chr4    52062187    TTT -
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'normalize_names_replacement_value' not found
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the package but getting some weird warnings while loading the package:

```
> BiocManager::install('decompTumor2Sig')
> library(decompTumor2Sig)
Warning messages:
1: In get(results[[i]], pos = which(search() == packages[[i]])) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(results[[i]], pos = which(search() == packages[[i]])) :
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1
3: In get(results[[i]], pos = which(search() == packages[[i]])) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
4: In get(results[[i]], pos = which(search() == packages[[i]])) :
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1
5: In get(results[[i]], pos = which(search() == packages[[i]])) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
6: In get(results[[i]], pos = which(search() == packages[[i]])) :
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1
7: In get(results[[i]], pos = which(search() == packages[[i]])) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
8: In get(results[[i]], pos = which(search() == packages[[i]])) :
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

Can you please assist?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting R fixed this issue.